# I want to get updated records from web sql server database into local database table through Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server

how to insert data from one database table to another database table in sql server 2008 When i am using web database and local Database on my pc. I want to get updated records from web sql server database into local database table  through Store Procedure.    what i have to do this?    Pls help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check linked server. http://www.jensbits.com/2010/11/10/create-linked-server-sql-server-2008/

after link the web server in to your local server, can access data easily.